# android emulator not working on react native cli

Tags: node.js, react-native

I made an app in **react native expo** and now i ejectd it to **react native cli**. But it shows following error. How can i solve this problem or run react native cli on android?

Below is my terminal error:

```
Jetifier found 1306 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
warn Invalid application's package name "com.adityasonawane.abcdKids" in 'AndroidManifest.xml'. Read guidelines for setting the package name here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app

Installing unimodules:
 unimodules-core@7.1.0 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\@unimodules\core
 unimodules-react-native-adapter@6.2.2 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\@unimodules\react-native-adapter
 expo-application@3.1.2 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\expo-application
 expo-av@9.1.2 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\expo-av
 expo-constants@10.1.3 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\expo-constants
 expo-error-recovery@2.1.0 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\expo-error-recovery
 expo-file-system@11.0.2 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\expo-file-system
 expo-font@9.1.0 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\expo-font
 expo-image-loader@2.1.1 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\expo-image-loader
 expo-keep-awake@9.1.2 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\expo-keep-awake
 expo-permissions@12.0.1 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\expo-permissions
 expo-splash-screen@0.10.2 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\expo-splash-screen
 expo-structured-headers@1.0.1 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\expo-structured-headers
 expo-updates@0.5.5 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\expo-updates
 unimodules-app-loader@2.1.0 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\unimodules-app-loader
 unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface@6.1.0 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface
 unimodules-camera-interface@6.1.0 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\unimodules-camera-interface
 unimodules-constants-interface@6.1.0 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\unimodules-constants-interface        
 unimodules-face-detector-interface@6.1.0 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\unimodules-face-detector-interface
 unimodules-file-system-interface@6.1.0 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\unimodules-file-system-interface
 unimodules-font-interface@6.1.0 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\unimodules-font-interface
 unimodules-image-loader-interface@6.1.0 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\unimodules-image-loader-interface
 unimodules-permissions-interface@6.1.0 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\unimodules-permissions-interface
 unimodules-sensors-interface@6.1.0 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\unimodules-sensors-interface
 unimodules-task-manager-interface@6.1.0 from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\unimodules-task-manager-interface

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\expo-application\android\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-application'.
> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-application'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 22s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

below is my buld.gradle code:

I tried to change package name, also updated path variables and gradel but it still giving me the error..

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 30
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post  build.gradle code here? I can help you

Comment: i updated above my build.gradle file. And also did some changes and now its giving following error:
`1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\abcdKids\node_modules\expo-application\android\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-application'.
> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.`

Comment: please answer , i am trying this from 3 days

Answer (score 0):

According to the errors , try following solutions.

1. Downgraded your gradle version and rerun the application.
   Downgrade to gradle-6.8.1-all.zip in gradle-wrapper.properties
2. If the above solution doesn't work. Reason may be your compiled sdk version is mismatched with your dependencies. Try downgrading and see if it works.

Comment: no, its not working, it still gives the error `* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-application'.
> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.`